# Could not load file or assembly 'Pricing.Contracts, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, reference, compiler-errors

I have my Client application that referenced WCF service. When i was running from local (http://localhost:2200/CalculationService.svc), I was able to debug and all working fine.

Now I deployed the WCF service to Dev environment and made sure Address is pointing to this new Dev URL and did "Update Service Reference". After i did this and running the code, it is throwing the error at the below line of Code.

```
 var client = new PricingService.CalculationServiceClient();
```

***Error:***

**Could not load file or assembly 'Pricing.Contracts, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.**

These are the things i tried.
When i build, it copies these dll's to the bin folder.

1. I removed the **Pricing.Contracts.dll** and referenced it. still error exists.
2. I closed the Solution, reopened, Removed the reference and added it again. Still the the same error.
3. just to test once again, i pointed to local service. Still the issue exists.

What should i do to get rid of this error?

Comment: The error message is pretty clear - it can't find the specified DLL.  Is the DLL in the bin folder of the service?

Comment: Yes. The dll is in the bin folder of the service.

Comment: Is there another DLL that `Pricing.Contracts` depends on that isn't in the bin folder?  Maybe it wasn't copied over?